# how to get js return value in html please find below code in screenshot

Tags: javascript, odoo

Please help me here
this is in my template
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to use javascript to write 'Hello' into the t-value of your "t" element?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `.innerHTML`.

> This line is the selector we write into a variable:
>
> ```
> var div = document.getElementById('my_val');
> ```
>
> And this line will append the `var msg` to the selected Element.
>
> ```
> div.innerHTML += msg;
> ```

**EDIT**

> `div.innerHTML += msg` will **append** the variable to the Element.
>
> If you write the line like this it will **overwrite** the existing
>   content in it.
>
> `div.innerHTML = msg`

*Here is the Code, notice that the Element `#my_val` is empty in the begining.*

```js
function my_function(){
  var msg = "Hello";
  var div = document.getElementById('my_val');
  div.innerHTML += msg;
  return msg;
}
my_function();
```

```html
<div id="my_val"></div>
```